# How to install older hoverfly version using brew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, hoverfly

I am trying to install 0.7 version of hoverfly on my mac os.

I am trying to use Homebrew for that.

Command I am using is :

```
brew install SpectoLabs/tap/hoverfly
```

but this installing latest version. I would like to install older version.

Can you specify way or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

First tap the formula repository from SpectoLab with:

```
brew tap SpectoLabs/tap
```

Then go to the directory where this formula is located:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/spectolabs
```

Get older commits:

```
git pull --unshallow
```

Checkout the the formula correponding to version 0.7

```
git checkout 0f54b7e23d5aa201d2fdd7
```

For an unknown reason the checksum of the archive has changed, so edit the formula (`./homebrew-tap/hoverfly.rb`) and replace:

```
sha256 "eec6b7a2e65a40021b3af2056519f5588757394ae82eb05caf2b73bb446172c0"
```

by

```
sha256 "5e9deb60b33c28e6b604f7f17b613c2f0d3a27c6330e2a405508d18498d44745"
```

(Do this at your own risk). Then install the formula with:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install hoverfly
```

For me it works.